# what is ldap, cas,shiboleth,opensso and their relationsihps

Tags: ldap, cas, opensso

I am a little confused about ldap, cas, shiboleth, opensso and their relationships

can any guru explain a little bit?

Thanks

Comment: rather you could tell what is the problem you are facing or what is the system you are trying to design. This is too vast to answer. LDAP is a access protocol for directory service. I dont know about cas. The others are for web single singon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you realy want to achive. But I found thes articles on wikipedia quite enlighting to get into this topic. Maybe it helps you to sort your problem out.

- [LDAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ldap)
- [CAS](http://www.jasig.org/cas)
- [OpenSSo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opensso)
- [Shiboleth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shibboleth_%28computer_security%29)

Comment: The CAS link is wrong. CAS in the provided context of ldap and SSO is definitively not Code Access Security (.net!) from MS